# Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 52 Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

I am new to this SQL scripting.

Getting error while trying to execute a delete command.

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 52 Conversion failed when converting
>   from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

And the script which I want to execute is:

```
-- attachments cleardown script
-- SJM 18/09/2009

set nocount on

declare @tableName nvarchar(200)
declare @columnName nvarchar(200)
declare @moduleName nvarchar(200)
declare @objectName nvarchar(200)
declare @attributeName nvarchar(200)
declare @dynamicSQL nvarchar(500)
declare @attachXML varchar(2000)
declare @fileGuid varchar(36)
declare @deletedXML varchar(100)
set @deletedXML = '<DataObjectAttachment><FileName>Deleted</FileName></DataObjectAttachment>'

declare attachCursor cursor fast_forward for
    select t5.md_name, t4.md_name, t3.md_title, t2.md_title, t1.md_title
        from md_attribute_type t1
        join md_class_type t2 on t1.md_class_type_guid = t2.md_guid
        join md_module t3 on t2.md_module_guid = t3.md_guid
        join md_database_column t4 on t1.md_database_column_guid = t4.md_guid
        join md_database_table t5 on t2.md_database_table_guid = t5.md_guid
        where t1.md_data_type = 16 and (
            t1.md_defined_by = 2 or
            t1.md_guid in ('103DBEAB-252F-4C9A-952A-90A7800FFC00', '2515E980-788D-443D-AA89-AA7CC3653867',
            '2D29495E-785E-4062-A49C-712A8136EBC7', '6A204C77-1007-48CC-B3BC-077B094540AE',
            '9A24BFEF-2CAB-4604-8814-656BA0B9ECC3', 'C368CB18-B4C4-4C4F-839C-F7E6E1E17AA8',
            '0814586B-A11E-4129-AF9B-9EC58120C9AF', 'BD4F73C4-07CA-4DC2-86AD-D713FBC6E7BA')
        )
        and t2.md_behaviour not in (2, 4, 8) -- exclude reference lists
        and t2.md_guid not in (select b.md_class_type_guid from md_class_behaviour b where b.md_behaviour_type_guid in 
            (select bt.md_guid from md_behaviour_type bt where bt.md_name in ('Category','Ranked'))) -- exclude categories and ordered lists
        and t3.md_name != 'Lifecycle'
        order by t3.md_title, t2.md_title, t1.md_title

open attachCursor
fetch next from attachCursor into @tableName, @columnName, @moduleName, @objectName, @attributeName
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    print 'Deleting from ' + @moduleName + ' -> ' + @objectName + ' (' + @tableName + ') -> ' + @attributeName + ' (' +  @columnName + ')...'
    set @dynamicSQL = 'declare attachCursor1 cursor fast_forward for'
    set @dynamicSQL = @dynamicSQL + ' select ' + @columnName + ' from ' + @tableName
    set @dynamicSQL = @dynamicSQL + ' where ' + @columnName + ' != ''' + @deletedXML + ''''
    exec sp_executesql @dynamicSQL

    open attachCursor1
    fetch next from attachCursor1 into @attachXML
    while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    begin
        set @fileGuid = substring(@attachXML, charindex('<Guid>', @attachXML) + 6, 36)
        delete from tps_attachment_data where tps_guid = convert(uniqueidentifier, @fileGuid)
        fetch next from attachCursor1 into @attachXML
    end
    close attachCursor1
    deallocate attachCursor1

    set @dynamicSQL = 'update ' + @tableName + ' set ' + @columnName + ' = ''' + @deletedXML + ''''
    set @dynamicSQL = @dynamicSQL + ' where ' + @columnName + ' != ''' + @deletedXML + ''''
    exec sp_executesql @dynamicSQL
    print '- Deleted ' + convert(varchar(10),@@Rowcount) + ' records.'

    fetch next from attachCursor into @tableName, @columnName, @moduleName, @objectName, @attributeName
end

close attachCursor
deallocate attachCursor

set nocount off

print char(13) + 'Attachment cleardown complete.'
print char(13) + 'Next steps to reclaim data file space:'
print '1. Take a backup!'
print '2. Shrink the database using the command: DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(''' + convert(varchar(100),SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')) + ''')'
print '3. Put the database into SINGLE_USER mode (Properties -> Options -> Restrict Access)'
print '4. Detach the database'
print '5. Rename the database .LDF log file'
print '6. Re-attach the database using single file method'
```

When I parse above script then it is completing successfully but on execution it throws the error.

Comment: Lets talk about your TPS Reports... line 52 is `tps_guid = convert(uniqueidentifier, @fileGuid)` so `@fileGuid/tps_guid` does not contain something that can be converted to a GUID, print it out and see whats up.

Comment: I tried finding if there is anything in tps_attachment_data and executed the command: select * from tps_attachment_data which gave me 311473 rows and all the rows have got tps_guid.

Comment: What about @fileGuid ?

Comment: How to check if there is anything @fileGuid? Please help me.

Comment: print it out after you assign it a value

Answer (score 1):

There are two new functions that have been available since SQL Server 2012: [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which complement the existing CAST and CONVERT functions.

If you cast an empty string to a unique identifier:

```
SELECT CAST('' as uniqueidentifier) uid
```

This would result in the error you are seeing. The same would be true or other strings that aren't GUIDs. Use TRY_CAST instead and the function returns a NULL instead of throwing an error. You can then skip records that don't have a valid GUID.

```
begin
    set @fileGuid = substring(@attachXML, charindex('<Guid>', @attachXML) + 6, 36)
    DECLARE @fileGuidOrNull uniqueidentifier = try_convert(uniqueidentifier, @fileGuid)
    IF @fileGuidOrNull IS NOT NULL
        delete from tps_attachment_data where tps_guid = @fileGuidOrNull
    fetch next from attachCursor1 into @attachXML
end
```